# Synchronization of two RLC circuits

Tags: capacitor, passive-networks, discharge, discharging

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIMlCM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose x amperes passes through the resistor R in circuit 1. Now if both switches in circuit 2 are turned on in synchronized manner, will the current flowing through resistor R be 2x now ?
(Assumption : All the capacitors are charged)

Comment: If you solve both circuits and obtain the current through each resistor, what do you get?

Comment: Is it possible to  close both the switches at the same time in circuit 2 in simulation?

Comment: Well, if I answer, what will you do? Go and simulate the circuit? Wouldn't that sort of defeat the purpose of me answering (or you asking)? Instead, you could be driven by your own curiosity and do it yourself, so that the joy of discovery for oneself is that much greater. However, I asked about solving the circuit, not simulating it, these are two different things. While you could go the quick way about it (simulation), solving it will give you some more insight, and, IMHO, that should count for more. But that's just me.

Comment: Actually I tried to solve it analytically but couldn't do it.

Comment: I would be much obliged if you can help me with this. @aconcernedcitizen

Comment: At the instant after both switches are closed, the inductor current will be zero, and therefore the voltage across R1 will be zero. After that it depends on the values of the components. Are L1 and L2 the same?  What about C1 and C2? To me, it seems kind of difficult to solve analytically if the component values are different. I am lazy. I would use a simulator.

Comment: L1=L2 and C1 = C2 @mkeith

Comment: OK, if C1 = C2 and L1 = L2 AND if Vc1 = Vc2 at time t=0, THEN you can convert circuit 2 into circuit 1.

Comment: "*Actually I tried to solve it analytically but couldn't do it*" -- can you show what you tried? If you do, people will be able to tell you easily where and what went wrong. Otherwise we'll just have to make presumptions, and that's not really how a Q&A site works.

Comment: *Is it possible to close both the switches at the same time in circuit 2 in simulation?* Of course. There are time-triggered switch elements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @mkeith and @a concerned citizen, a simulation helps very much.

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9i8tmfrxg558beg/R-L-C%20switching%20v010.cir?dl=0) to file. Made with FREE [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm).

Here is the behavior in two configurations.
The same components just changed one initial condition for one capacitor in the double circuit.
Pictures are at starting time ... Oscillations are vanishing.

[image]

[image]

Equations are now up to you.

Last example.  Switch is in red circle.

[image]

Comment: Can we explain which initial condition did you changed for one capacitor in double circuit and why ?

Comment: The thing I changed is the initial voltage of C2 (200 V in place of 100 V). For just seeing the result. And I found a very "different" (oscillatory) behavior. Just a thought. I did not try changing anything else (values of L1, L2, C1, or C2). Interesting to do in simulation first.

Comment: 1. Are you using PSpice for these simulation? If you still have that simulation file, can you study the effect of change in inductance in double circuit. I-e Increasing L1 and L2 by same value, decreasing them by same value and by introducing some difference in L1 and L2

Comment: I am using microcap v12. Will add the link to the software and add a file link in the answer. There is a animated switch you can open. Run transient analysis and click on the switch 2 times to open.